# Cocos2d Frame Rate

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to change the frame rate of one layer while keeping the frame rate of another constant?  I am currently using [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] setTimeScale:X]; which effects all layers of a scene.  I want it to just affect a single layer.

WORD

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an interval-based scheduled event using `schedule:interval:` to give different layers didn't framerates. Interval is determined in seconds, so you could do `1.0f/60.0f` for 60 FPS (though don't do that, use scheduleUpdate for anything that matches your game's framerate).